# SERVLET_MAPPING Suffix .do in Struts1 to Spring Boot Migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, struts-1

Working on a migration from Struts1 to Springbooted Struts1, I faced action resolving issues.

Using `ServletRegistrationBean`, Struts1 would behave as expected (when someAction.do is invoked, it works correctly).

The problem, however, is related to the generated HTML with:

`<html:form action="someAction" .../>`

The HTML rendering of `someAction` must be suffixed with `.do`, but it was not.

`<form action="someAction" .../>`

After debugging html taglib, I discovered that the equivalent parameter in web.xml, `servlet-mapping` is not actually replicated in the `ServletRegistrationBean`<s>, although `.addUrlMappings("*.do")` was specified</s>.

In the image below, pageContext.getAttribute() retrieves '*.do' for a basic Struts1 application, but it returns null in the Springbooted application.

[image]

What should I do to make `pageContext.getAttribute(Globals.SERVLET_KEY, PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);` return '*.do'?

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean strutsActionServlet() {
        
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
    servletRegistrationBean.setServlet(new myActionServlet());
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(10);
    servletRegistrationBean.setName("StrutsServlet");
    servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("*.do");

    servletRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("config", "/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml");
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it through `ServletContextEvent`:

```
public void contextInitialized (ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext ();
    sc.setAttribute(Globals.SERVLET_KEY, "*.do");
}
```